# Detect an empty [{}] json object in managed code

Tags: json, c#-4.0, xml-parsing

Our application uses json files for configuration.

1. If the file has configuration data we parse it and all goes well.
2. If the file has bad data [{ asdf 34453 %^$% dfgdsf }] we handle just fine
3. If the config file is missing then we handle that.

The scenario I'm trying to figure out is if it is an empty object such as [{}] I'm looking for a reliable way by checking the first Xnode, last Xnode, Xattribute..something because HasElements will return true for an empty object.

Please don't suggest using 3rd part libraries etc. Not happening as decided by others.

The code I am using:

```
private static bool TryParseJson(MemoryStream msJson)
{
   bool IsValid = false;
   XElement root;

   XmlReader xReader = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(msJson, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());

   //an empty json file ( [] ) will parse but have no elements hence the elements check.
   //a file full of giberish...incorrect json format will fail to parse and throw exception hence the try catch

   try
   {
     root = XElement.Load(xReader);
   }
   catch
   {
     return IsValid;
   }

    //an empty file ( [{}] will return positive for HasElements so we also get ?????
    XNode ???? = root.FirstNode;

   if (root.HasElements && !???)
   {
      IsValid = true;
      return IsValid;
   }

   return IsValid;
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular known element that must be in your config file for it to be considered valid?  If so, why not just check for the existence of that?

Comment: Well see there isn't. It's a generic so that it can be used in our internal library in many different scenarios so I'm looking for something like FirstNode == null or similiar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a way to handle an empty object. My testing with valid json and empty json shows that an empty object [{}] will still return a single element but there will be NO nodes in that element so I went with this:

```
//an empty file ( [{}] will return positive for HasElements so we also get 
bool IsEmptyObject = (root.Elements().Nodes().Count() > 0) ? true : false;
```

I'd still be interested in hearing the contributions of others.

Thanks